# SELECT and then INSERT data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if there is a entry from today and if not then add one, if it already exists then not.
Current code is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql .= "SELECT plusamount AS plustotal, minusamount AS minustotal FROM   Juuli WHERE reg_date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "It already exists!";
} else {
    echo "autowrite should run";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO Juuli(minusamount) VALUES (0); ";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: and this isn't working... how? Other than you're not executing your `insert`, just APPENDING it to the original query string...

Comment: if reg_date is of DATETIME format you need to only get the date, something like `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE DATE(reg_date) = CURDATE()` but this is a big guess

Comment: What is the problem? Where is it failing?

Comment: Have you ran the query in the terminal to see if it actually returns data before running it with PHP?  If so what results are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SELECT statement is working the way you want it to directly from the database, the following should work.  (notice the replacement of `.=` with `=`)

```
$sql = "SELECT plusamount AS plustotal, minusamount AS minustotal FROM Juuli WHERE reg_date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "It already exists!";
} else {
    echo "autowrite should run";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Juuli (minusamount) VALUES (0)";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
}
$conn->close();
```